# bootstrap height inherit is not working as without bootstrap does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

the main issue is that I can't set a height in % for the inner divs.
I read in one of the threads that I need to set a wrapper with a height in px and the inner div I can set in % - and it works, just not in bootstrap.

I don't want to overload the page with unnecessary elements, so I wanted to inherit the height from the body ( whatever that will be ).

The bootstrap set the height in someway, and when I inherit the height to one of the divs on the way, it receive it OK, but the inner div still doesn't accept the % height.

Examples:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HYtcz/ - CSS (px) without bootstrap, working
http://jsfiddle.net/HYtcz/1/ - CSS (%) without bootstrap, working
http://jsfiddle.net/tH9En/4/ - Adding the bootstrap lib - doesn't work.
```

Code:

```
    <html>
<head>
        <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">    <style>
            .main {
                background: yellow;
                height: inherit;
            }
            .list {
                overflow: scroll;
                background: gray;
                width: 400px;
                height: 20%;
            }
            .list table tr td {
                line-height: 50px;
            }
            </style>
</head>
<body>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                        <p>adfasdf</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
</body>
    </html>
```

I'm looking for either of the answers ( how to set height in % in bootstrap, of fix the above example )
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add this to your "Adding the bootstrap lib " version

```
html, body { height: 1011px; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zHDFP/)

Comment: no, but that's the thing :) bootstrap is setting it according to the screen size, no ? if you run the same JS code to print the screen size, it will give you something

Comment: if you can use position:absolute in your project, then go for it may be it can help you to solve your problem